# Combine pipeable functions in code blocks

Tags: r, dplyr, eval, magrittr

I would like to summarise pipeable functions (of magrittr/dplyr) into shorter function-"blocks" (to hopefully have more readable code). For example:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- tbl_df(data.frame(A = rep(LETTERS[2:5], each = 5),
                       M = rep(letters[1:2], times = 10),
                       X = round(rnorm(20, 10, 2), 1)))

# I want to replace this
# ----------------------
d %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(X = mean(X)) -> d_test_1

# with this
# ---------
my_mean <- function(d, by_var, x) {
  expr <- substitute(by_var) # group variable, seems ok
  expr_2 <- substitute(expression(x = mean(x))) # calculate mean
  print(deparse(expr_2))
  # problem: x = mean(x) is only substituted to x = mean(X) .. 1 capital x, should be 2
  expr_3 <- parse(text = paste(deparse(substitute(x)), "=mean(", 
                               deparse(substitute(x)), ")"))
  print(deparse(expr_3))
  # expr_3 does not work either
  d %>%
    group_by(eval(expr)) %>%
    #summarise(X = mean(X)) -> d # uses right group variable
    summarise(eval(expr_3)) -> d # uses wrong group variable <> side-effect of "expr"?
  invisible(d)
}

# this is the short version I am after
d %>%
  my_mean(A, X) -> d_test_2
d_test_1
d_test_2
```

Thx & kind regards

Comment: I suggested you read this: [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: Is your edit a working answer to your question? In that case, you can post it as an answer to your own question, and even accept it to signal that it solves the problem

Comment: see also `purrr::compose`

Comment: @Moody: Sorry, I don't get it. How do you handle the different args of group_by and summarise? (Can only find `compose`('!', is.null)`.)

Comment: I assume your general issue is not precisely the one you laid here, so I just meant to say `compose ` could come handy. You can overcome some of the issues related to other arguments by using it with partial or wrapping your functions into anonymous functions on the spot.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe somebody else does not know where to look either:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- tbl_df(data.frame(A = rep(LETTERS[2:5], each = 5),
                       M = rep(letters[1:2], times = 10),
                       X = round(rnorm(20, 10, 2), 1),
                       stringsAsFactors = F))

my_mean <- function(d, by_var, x) {
  d %>%
    group_by(!!enquo(by_var)) %>%
    summarise(!!quo_name(enquo(x)) := mean(!!enquo(x))) 
}

d %>%
  my_mean(A, X) -> want
want
```